# AWS lambda function can't locate .env file from a docker container issue

Tags: docker, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, docker-compose

I am new to AWS and docker in general. I am trying to get data from a news API and save it in a S3 bucket. I was able to create a docker image and ran it locally by using the AWS Secret key and Access keyId specified in an env file. Now I want to create a lambda function using the container, but AWS lambda function couldn't see the access key. I am not sure I am using the best practice.

Here is my Dockerfile

```
WORKDIR ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

ADD ./semanticnewssearch/handler.py handler.py

ADD requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt --target "${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}"

CMD ["handler.handler"]
```

My docker-compose.yml:

```
services:
  test:
    # Here you can specify an env-file with variables
    # that can be used in the docker-container,
    # BUT these variables can not be used here in the
    # docker-compose using ${...} UNLESS it is a file named
    # ".env". This file (in the same directory) is always
    # loaded into the docker-compose, but not into the
    # docker-containers unless the variables are mapped in the
    # environment option below or using the env_file option here.
    env_file: .env
    container_name: Data_streaming
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment: # specify the env-variables here
      # secret ones in .env file or system
      newsapikey: ${newsapikey}
      AWSAccessKeyId: ${AWSAccessKeyId}
      AWSSecretKey: ${AWSSecretKey}
      PYTHONUNBUFFERED: 1
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
```

my handler script

```
import sys
import requests
from urllib import response
import json
import datetime
import time
import botocore
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()


NEWS_API = 'XXXXXXX'
country = 'XXXXXX'
api_key = os.getenv('newsapikey')
ACCESS_KEY = os.getenv('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
SECRET_KEY = os.getenv('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')

url = (f'{NEWS_API}'
        f'country={country}'
        'pageSize=100&'
        f'apiKey={api_key}')

## Save news data to s3 bucket
def save_news(data, filename):
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3',
                        aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
                        aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY)
    s3Object = s3.Object('bucketname', filename)
    try:
        s3Object.put(Body=json.dumps(data).encode('UTF-8'))
    except ClientError as e:
        print(e)
        print("Something went wrong. Please try again later.")
        sys.exit()
    print("Data saved successfully.")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("Exiting...")
    sys.exit()

## Get news data from s3 bucket
def get_news(filename):
    s3 = boto3.client('s3',
                        aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
                        aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY)
    try:
        data  = s3.get_object(Bucket='bukectname', Key = filename)
        data_ = data["Body"].read().decode()
        data_ = json.loads(data_)
    except ClientError as e:
        print(e)
        print("Something went wrong. Please try again later.")
        sys.exit()
    print("Data retrieved successfully.")
    return data_

def request_news():
    try:
        response = requests.get(url)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print("Something went wrong. Please try again later.")
        sys.exit()
    return response.json()

def handler(event, context):
    data = request_news()
    ### Save data with datetime as filename
    directory = 'data/'
    filename = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    save_news(data, 'data/' + filename + '.json')
    return
```